# Dynamic SQL server query with variables (Problems executing)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is a far smaller version of a query that basically needs a variable of the table on which everything is run.

When I run the procedure I get the error message:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.

```
alter procedure james_tester
@tablename nvarchar(200)
as

        BEGIN
        declare @sql nvarchar(max)

        set @sql =  

        '
        select * from ' 

        + @tablename

            EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

        END
```

To fix this i tried using things like quotename and played around with the format but nothing seems to have worked yet.

execute james_tester 'dbo.Calendar table' (That is the table I am wanting to query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how you call your procedure.

execute james_tester 'dbo.Calendar **table**'

should be

execute james_tester 'dbo.Calendar'

Hence the error message :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword '**table**'.

Answer (score 1):

`Table` is a keyword of sql server. 
So you couldn't use it as an alias with out `[]`.
Try this

```
execute james_tester 'dbo.Calendar [table]'
```

or

```
execute james_tester 'dbo.Calendar t'
```

or

```
execute james_tester 'dbo.Calendar'
```

Comment: Thanks. Selected * into a table 'calendar', repeated all steps and everything worked!